# Which is most popular language and framework for development in 2021?

Tags: frameworks

Looking for the best solution for my new project. Need to know which language or framework would be most suitable for a web development project in the long run. I am thinking about python and Django.

Answer (score 0):

The right technology is one that you are familiar with and are comfortable with.
There is no definite answer. If you are comfortable with Django then it is the right technology. Lots of successful projects have been done by Django.
For someone else familiar with Java, Spring would be a good choice.
Personally I prefer Golang. I feel that Go is more intuitive, clear, and Debugging is easier and clearer than others.
These things remain personal preferences. Yeah . Some types of projects are more suitable for languages or technologies than others. But the majority of projects can be implemented with any technology.